# How can I pass a spacebar variable inside a sub template call in Meteor?

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I'm using dburles package for Google Maps implementation.
I have a Google Maps instance in a template, and I would like to pass an ID dynamically, but does not work. See the example below:

HTML:

```
{{> googleMap name="{{post._id}}" options=MapOptions}}
```

How can I pass the post._id to the map name?

EDIT:

This is the context (Simplified):

HTML:

```
<template name="Example">
  {{#each post in posts}}
    {{> ExampleDetail post = post }}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="ExampleDetail">
  {{> googleMap name="{{post._id}}" options=MapOptions}}
</template>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
Template.ExampleDetail.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready(this.data.post._id, function(map) {
    console.log("IT WORKS!");
  });
});
```

When I pass an ID string in the name (for testing), it works, like this:

```
{{> googleMap name="tGuGrJeugLgNDkzh9" options=MapOptions}}
```

But with spacebars, the map does not work, not showing "IT WORKS!" in the console...

Thanks for the comments and sorry for my english!

Comment: This needs more context, especially errors, the template parts around this code (where you get the `post` document) as well has helpers and publications / subscriptions if in use. Otherwise it will be nearly impossible to find out why your won't pass the I'd.

Comment: Even if you pass, how are you checking its been set?

Comment: show more code.

Comment: `name=post._id`

Comment: I edited the question...
@michel-floyd this not works...

Comment: @MichelFloyd now it works with your comment!! It's possible that I test this in other context, but I tested again and now it's working!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the same pattern as `{{> ExampleDetail post = post }}`. In a handlebars template, you can't nest tags, but you can use variable names directly. So:

```
{{> googleMap name=post._id options=MapOptions}}
```

The variables may come from a helper function or any variable available in the same context.

Comment: Yes! This works! Thanks! Is the same answer of Michel Floyd.